# Sort numbers in an array without changing even numbers position using Java-8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I’m learning Java 8 streams. Tell me pls, how can I write a `sortArray` method more compactly?

```
import org.junit.Test;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;

public class TestStream {

    /*
     * Sort numbers in an array without changing even numbers position
     */

    @Test
    public void test_1() {
        int[] nonSorted = new int[]{3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 9, 8, 7, 0};
        int[] expected = new int[]{1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};

        Integer[] arr = sortArray(nonSorted);
        int[] sorted = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sorted[i] = arr[i];
        }

        assertArrayEquals(expected, sorted);
    }

    private Integer[] sortArray(int[] array) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> even = extractEven(array);
        Integer[] withoutEvens = removeEven(array);
        int length = even.size() + withoutEvens.length;
        Integer[] result = new Integer[length];
        Arrays.sort(withoutEvens);
        for (int i = 0; i < withoutEvens.length; i++) {
            result[i] = withoutEvens[i];
        }
        even.forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.arraycopy(result, k, result, k + 1, length - k - 1);
            result[k] = v;
        });

        return result;
    }


    private Map<Integer, Integer> extractEven(int[] array) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
                map.put(i, array[i]);
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    private Integer[] removeEven(int[] array) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
                list.add(array[i]);
            }
        }

        Integer[] a = new Integer[list.size()];
        return list.toArray(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can think of a solution like:
First we extract the odd integers from the `nonSorted[]` and put them on a `stack` in sorted fashion.

> **Why we should use the `stack` in a sorted fashion??**
>
> The final array
>   needs to be sorted on odd `Integers` basis, the stack follows FIFO(First in Last
>   Out) policy.

Now we take an `Instream` and run it from `0` to `nonSorted.length-1` and check the original `nonSorted` for the odd `Integer`; as soon as we find one we replace it with the first element of the stack and `pop()` the element from the `stack`.

> **Note:** One needs to play around the stack as not every time you will
>   need sorted elements in the stack, but in OP's case this happens to
>   be.

```
int[] nonSorted = new int[]{3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 9, 8, 7, 0};

LinkedList<Integer> stack = Arrays.stream(nonSorted)
            .sorted().filter(s -> s % 2 != 0).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));

int[] expected = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, nonSorted.length - 1)
       .map(s -> nonSorted[s] % 2 != 0 ? stack.pop():nonSorted[s]) 
       .toArray();
```

Comment: Looks much better than I could come up with. +1

Comment: Wow! it is amazing! stack is interesting, i think

Answer (score 2):

I really liked the idea of using a sorted `Stack`, but it is not easily parallelizable and got me curious how to solve that.

My idea is sorting indices of uneven elements and depending on the position of the index we can distinguish during the creation of the result array if a number is even or not.

```
public int[] sortUnevenElements(int[] nonSorted) {
    int[] unevenIndices = IntStream.range(0, nonSorted.length).filter(i -> nonSorted[i] % 2 != 0).toArray();
    int[] sortedUnevenIndices = Arrays.stream(unevenIndices, 0, unevenIndices.length).boxed()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> nonSorted[i])).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    return IntStream.range(0, nonSorted.length).map(i -> {
        int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(unevenIndices, i);
        return idx >= 0 ? nonSorted[sortedUnevenIndices[idx]] : nonSorted[i];
    }).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you mean by Java-8 is using `Stream`s and other APIs introduced since that release. You already have a very well-performing code in my opinion though. The way I could think of breaking down the problem is as follows -

1. Find the odd and even numbers and their mappings to the current indexes. Such that even values with their indexes would remain fixed.
2. Upon the odd numbers and their indexes, remap the values sorting them naturally.
3. Once all of this is done, merge these split odd-even maps based upon the indexes.
4. Retrieve the values from this merged result.

Overall implementation of this would look something like -

```
private Integer[] sortArrayStream(Integer[] array) {
    Map<Boolean, Map<Integer, Integer>> evenOdds = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> array[i] % 2 == 0,
                    Collectors.toMap(o -> o, i -> array[i]))); //1

    Map<Integer, Integer> oddSorted = remapWithSorting(evenOdds.get(Boolean.FALSE)); // 2

    Map<Integer, Integer> overall = new HashMap<>(evenOdds.get(Boolean.TRUE));
    overall.putAll(oddSorted); // part of 3

    return overall.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()) // remaining of 3
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // 4
            .toArray(Integer[]::new); 
}


private Map<Integer, Integer> remapWithSorting(Map<Integer, Integer> initialIndexMapping) {
    List<Integer> oddIndexes = new ArrayList<>(initialIndexMapping.keySet());
    List<Integer> sortedOdds = initialIndexMapping.values().stream()
            .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return IntStream.range(0, sortedOdds.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(oddIndexes::get, sortedOdds::get));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an insertion sort trial with streams. The `nonSorted` array is streamed and collected to a `new int[]`. If the value from `nonSorted` array is even it is just copied, otherwise if it is odd an insertion sort is run just for odd values already present in the result.

```
int[] sort = IntStream.range(0, nonSorted.length)
            .collect(() -> new int[nonSorted.length], (ints, i) -> {
                ints[i] = nonSorted[i];
                if (nonSorted[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    AtomicInteger current = new AtomicInteger(i);
                    IntStream.iterate(i - 1, 
                                     (v) -> current.get() > 0 && v >= 0,
                                     (v) -> --v)
                            .forEach(ind -> {
                                if (ints[ind] % 2 != 0) {
                                    if (ints[ind] > nonSorted[i]) {
                                        ints[current.get()] = ints[ind];
                                        ints[ind] = nonSorted[i];
                                        current.set(ind);
                                    } else {
                                        current.set(-1);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }, (a1, a2) -> {
            });
```